# vb.net wpf popup no focus

Tags: wpf, vb.net, popup

I have several popups in my WPF application, which work fine.

However, this last one is not accepting focus or input in the textboxes. And I don't see why.

```
                    <Label x:Name="lblSearch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5" Height="30" Width="Auto">Search</Label>
                    <TextBox Name="txtSearch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5" Height="30" Width="200" IsReadOnly="False" IsEnabled="True"></TextBox>
                    <Button Name="btnSearch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource ButtonSmall}" Template="{DynamicResource BlackButton}" Margin="5">Search</Button>

                    <Label x:Name="lblReplace" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5" Height="30" Width="Auto">Replace</Label>
                    <TextBox Name="txtReplace" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5" Height="30" Width="200" IsReadOnly="False" IsEnabled="True"></TextBox>
                    <Button Name="btnReplace" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource ButtonSmall}" Template="{DynamicResource BlackButton}" Margin="5">Replace</Button>

                    <Button Name="btnStopSearch"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ButtonSmall}" Template="{DynamicResource BlackButton}" Margin="5">Done</Button>

                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    </DockPanel>
                </local:GridEx>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

I tried this code to force focus on it but to no avail:

```
Private searchWhere As String = Nothing
Private Sub txtTypeEditor_keyDown(sender As Object, e As Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtTypeEditor.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Forms.Keys.F AndAlso e.Control AndAlso Not e.Alt AndAlso Not e.Shift Then
        PopupSearch.IsOpen = True
        txtSearch.Focus()
        Keyboard.Focus(txtSearch)
        searchWhere = "TypeEditor"
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Popup1_Opened(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PopupSearch.Opened
    txtSearch.Focus()
    Keyboard.Focus(txtSearch)
End Sub
```

It appears the txtTypeEditor holds onto the focus. Any idea how to blur it?

I now have a workaround: If i blur the textbox by focusing another textBox then the popup accepts the focus.

However if the user clicks into the txtTypeEditor textbox and then clicks an inputfield in the popup, then the mouse focus switches to the popup, but the keyboard focus stays with the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess: 
Is it maybe related to the `txtTypeEditor_keyDown` event stays somehow in the txtTypeEditor?
You could give it a try with `keyPress` instead (if it is not affecting any other part of your code)

Comment: I don't know how to check for CTRL-F key with keyPress

Comment: you could capture the CTRL press via _keydown and set in the handler a bool value ctrl = true, then check in the _keyPress for "F" beeing pressed and ctrl = true